# Mocking crypto/ssh/terminal

Tags: go

Has anyone had any success or have any ideas on what would be the best way to mock entry (for testing purposes) to a `term.ReadPassword(int(os.Stdin.Fd()))` call in the `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal` package?

I have tried creating a temp file (vs `os.Stdin`) and writing string values like `testing\n` or `testing\r` to the temp file but I get the error `inappropriate ioctl for device`. I'm guessing it is something TTY related or a specific format that is missing(?) but I really am not sure.

Help appreciated.

Comment: in what way are you trying to test `terminal.ReadPassword`? Are you trying to add a test to that package? That function can only work on a terminal, so if you don't have a terminal then don't use that function.

Comment: I wrote a library that uses that function. Was trying to create a test, mostly to ensure that I had full coverage, but its not 100% necessary.

I'm using `bufio.Reader` for regular input and I can modify the file to handle that test case, but `terminal.ReadPassword` doesn't seem to work the same way.

Library is here (not meant to be a plug) in case you have suggestions: https://github.com/goposse/tardy

Comment: You just need to make using ReadPassword conditional on having a tty. You could do that by wrapping it in another function, mocking out a PasswordReader as Corbin suggested, or just adding another condition to the if statement to check IsTerminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are stubbing this test by creating a fake file that `os.Stdin` is referencing, your tests will become tremendously OS specific when you try to handle `ReadPassword()`. This is because under the hood Go is compiling separate syscalls depending on the OS. `ReadPassword()` is implemented [here](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/911fafb28f4ee7c7bd483539a6c96190bbbccc3f/ssh/terminal/util.go#L94), but the syscalls based on architecture and OS are in [this directory](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/0104a31b8fbcbe52728a08867b26415d282c35d2/src/syscall). As you can see there are many. I cannot think of a good way to stub this test in the way you are specifying.

With the limited understanding of your problem the solution I would propose would be to inject a simple interface along the lines of:

```
type PasswordReader interface {
    ReadPassword(fd int) ([]byte, error)
}

func (pr PasswordReader) ReadPassword(fd int) ([]byte, error) {
    return terminal.ReadPassword(fd)
}
```

This way you can pass in a fake object to your tests, and stub the response to `ReadPassword`. I know this feels like writing your code for your tests, but you can reframe this thought as `terminal` is an outside dependency (I/O) that should be injected! So now your tests are not only ensuring your code works, but actually helping you make good design decisions.

Comment: Make sense and actually this helps to tidy up that part of the code also. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

Corbin's example prompted me to look into interface mocking and prompted me to write up a basic example:

```
// getter.go
package cmd

import (
    "errors"
    "syscall"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
)

type PasswordReader interface {
    ReadPassword() (string, error)
}

type StdInPasswordReader struct {
}

func (pr StdInPasswordReader) ReadPassword() (string, error) {
    pwd, error := terminal.ReadPassword(int(syscall.Stdin))
    return string(pwd), error
}

func readPassword(pr PasswordReader) (string, error) {
    pwd, err := pr.ReadPassword()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    if len(pwd) == 0 {
        return "", errors.New("empty password provided")
    }
    return pwd, nil
}

func Run(pr PasswordReader) (string, error) {
    pwd, err := readPassword(pr)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return string(pwd), nil
}
```

In the test, we can mock errors and simulating no `stdin` input.

```
// getter_test.go
package cmd_test
import (
    "errors"
    "testing"

    "github.com/petems/passwordgetter/cmd"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

type stubPasswordReader struct {
    Password    string
    ReturnError bool
}

func (pr stubPasswordReader) ReadPassword() (string, error) {
    if pr.ReturnError {
        return "", errors.New("stubbed error")
    }
    return pr.Password, nil
}

func TestRunReturnsErrorWhenReadPasswordFails(t *testing.T) {
    pr := stubPasswordReader{ReturnError: true}
    result, err := cmd.Run(pr)
    assert.Error(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, errors.New("stubbed error"), err)
    assert.Equal(t, "", result)
}

func TestRunReturnsPasswordInput(t *testing.T) {
    pr := stubPasswordReader{Password: "password"}
    result, err := cmd.Run(pr)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, "password", result)
}
```

There are also tools like gomock, testify and counterfeiter that basically do all the heavy lifting for you, and you can add in generator steps into the code:

```
//go:generate mockgen -destination=../mocks/mock_getter.go -package=mocks github.com/petems/passwordgetter/cmd PasswordReader
```

You then include the mock that gets generated in your test:

```
package cmd_test

import (
    "testing"
    "errors"

    "github.com/golang/mock/gomock"

    "github.com/petems/passwordgetter/mocks"
    "github.com/petems/passwordgetter/cmd"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestRunReturnsErrorWhenEmptyString(t *testing.T) {

    mockCtrl := gomock.NewController(t)
  defer mockCtrl.Finish()

  mockPasswordReader := mocks.NewMockPasswordReader(mockCtrl)

  mockPasswordReader.EXPECT().ReadPassword().Return("", nil).Times(1)

    result, err := cmd.Run(mockPasswordReader)
    assert.Error(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, errors.New("empty password provided"), err)
    assert.Equal(t, "", result)
}
```